# How to find Amazon Linux 2023 version?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When I run the `dnf check-update` command on my Amazon Linux server it appears as follows:

```
Amazon Linux 2023 repository                                        361  B/s | 3.6 kB     00:10
==================================================================================================== WARNING:   A newer release of "Amazon Linux" is available.

  Available Versions:

  Version 2023.0.20230517:
    Run the following command to upgrade to 2023.0.20230517:

      dnf upgrade --releasever=2023.0.20230517

    Release notes:
     https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/release-notes/relnotes-2023.0.20230517.html

  Version 2023.0.20230607:
    Run the following command to upgrade to 2023.0.20230607:

      dnf upgrade --releasever=2023.0.20230607

    Release notes:
     https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/release-notes/relnotes-2023.0.20230607.html

  Version 2023.0.20230614:
    Run the following command to upgrade to 2023.0.20230614:

      dnf upgrade --releasever=2023.0.20230614

    Release notes:
     https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/release-notes/relnotes-2023.0.20230614.html

...


====================================================================================================

apache-maven.noarch                          3.5.2-1.el6                           epel-apache-maven
```

It seems to show all the versions I can upgrade to.
I want to compare it with my current version So I tried running the command `cat /etc/os-release`

```
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2023"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="2023"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:al2023"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2023"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2023"
HOME_URL="https://aws.amazon.com/linux/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-linux-2023"
SUPPORT_END="2028-03-01"
```

But I don't see the exact current version of Amazon Linux 2023: 2023.X.XXXXXXXX. Is there any way to know?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know exact version of Amazon Linux 2?](https://repost.aws/questions/QUy_4gQAR6RYyez2n82TOIxw/how-to-know-exact-version-of-amazon-linux-2)

Comment: @Justinas Sorry but I don't have access to AWS Console, only through ec2 using SSH. I have looked at your link before but I don't have any idea from the answer in that article

Comment: @Justinas I see an answer like this but I don't quite understand it: you could retrieve the ami-id by calling the instance metadata service and then use that to perform a query against the AWS API to extract the needed data.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Amazon Linux 2023 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/ug/deterministic-upgrades-usage.html):

> You can change the value of releasever using one of the following methods. These methods are listed in descending system priority. This means that method 1 overrides methods 2 and 3, and method 2 overrides method 3.

1. The value in the command line flag, --releasever=latest, if it's used.
2. The value that's specified in the override variable file, /etc/dnf/vars/releasever, if it's set.
3. The currently installed version of the system-release package.

So `releasever` can be found with the one-liner:
`cat /etc/dnf/vars/releasever || rpm -q system-release`

**Original answer**

Can be found like so:
`cat /var/log/dnf.log | grep -i "ddebug releasever:" | rev | cut -f 1 -d " " | rev | tail -n 1`

To double check run `dnf list system-release`. The numbers should be identical.
The packages `amazon-linux-repo-s3` or `kernel-livepatch-repo-s3` can be used in place of `system-release`.